# HTML overlapping elements in absolute elements

Tags: html, css, css-float

I design a master layout for my application. I made it in pure html/css just to keep it simple during the layout development. I use bootstrap (so jquery also included) and less (for my own less file):

```
  <div id="header" class="layoutOuter">
    <div class="layoutInner">
      <div class="layoutItem">
        <div class="btn-group-sm pull-left">
          <button class="btn btn-default">Head Left 1</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default">Head Left 2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group-sm pull-right">
          <button class="btn btn-default">Head Right 1</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default">Head Right 2</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu" class="layoutOuter">
    <div class="layoutInner">
      <div class="layoutItem">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-block">Menu 1</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-block">Menu 2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="layoutOuter">
    <div class="layoutInner">
      <div class="layoutItem">
        <div>C0 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C0 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C0 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C0 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Less:

```
@bodyBackground: white;
@pageWidth: 1024px;
@headerHeight: 30px;
@leftMenuWidth: 100px;
@headerContentDistance: 6px;

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: @bodyBackground;
}
.layoutOuter {
    text-align: center;
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    >.layoutInner {
        text-align: left;
        display: inline-block;
        >.layoutItem {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }
}
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-color: inherit;
    z-index: 100;
    >div.layoutInner {
        background-color: inherit;
        >div.layoutItem {
            background-color: inherit;
            height: @headerHeight;
            width: @pageWidth;
        }
    }
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: @headerHeight + @headerContentDistance;
    >div.layoutInner {
        text-align: left;
        width: @pageWidth;
        >div.layoutItem {
            z-index: 101;
            float: right;
            width: @pageWidth - @leftMenuWidth;
        }
    }
}
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: @headerHeight + @headerContentDistance;
    background-color: inherit;
    z-index: 100;
    >div.layoutInner {
        text-align: left;
        width: @pageWidth;
        background-color: inherit;
        z-index: 100;
        >div.layoutItem {
            z-index: 100;
            width: @leftMenuWidth;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem started when I resize the browser to lesser width. When scrolling, my content was visible under the menu elements. I start to play with background color with no success. Then the z-index, but somehow the #content>div.layoutInner>div.layoutItem with z-index:101 was overlapped by the #menu>div.layoutInner with z-index:100
Any idea how to solve this "little" issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is how the `z-index` stacking works.

In this case, you actually need to put a `z-index` on `#content` that is higher than the `z-index` of `#menu`, as those two elements exist in the same stacking context.

Two elements are **only** in the same stacking context if they are direct siblings. In this case, `#content` and `#menu` are siblings. You can `z-index` `#content>.layoutOuter` all you want but if the `z-index` of `#menu` is higher than the `z-index` of `#content`, `#menu` will display higher than it no matter the values.

Comment: Understand. But it means I can't solve my problem. If you see my #context and #menu elements, both full width to the windows (right:0, left:0) and fixed position in order to put the child elements to the center(text-align: center). Both #menu>div.layoutInner and #context>div.layoutInner has @pageWidth width and I float the #context layoutItem to the right and left the #menu layoutItem in the flow. Both layoutItem has concrete width in order to be side-by-side each other. This layout will have two option. Fixed and absolute menu. In case of absolute menu it works well.

Comment: Can you put together a pen or fiddle or something to show what you're getting? There's too much code for me to manually parse it in my head.

Comment: Hi here is the original which is wrong: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxkAc and the new one with the partial solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IEjfH I know that some content is visible above menu and the bigger problem is the right header buttons not visible in small window (it can't be repair I think). (And thanks for the pen. I didn't know it :D)

Comment: It's a `z-index` fix. I added one line to `#menu`, and it works. http://codepen.io/rupertjeff/pen/DbLym

Answer (score 0):

I finally - it's lasts a day - come up with a partial solution.
I switch the `#menu` and the `#content`. In this way the the menu overlap the content. It can't hide the context because the `.layoutItem` of the context is not so wide to slip under the menu (In case the window width is at least 1024px) and if I scroll left-right (in case of narrow window) the content slip under the menu and it was visible between the right side menu buttons. So I change the #menu>div.layoutInner>div.layoutItem `background-color` to `@bodyBackground`.